# 2 Colors on 1 object

Tags: unity, color

After some tutorials this is my first own object in blender -a race track for unity. The main object should be white, but the road itself should be red, without creating 2 objects.
So I marked all the road-faces and assigned them to a new Material. But somehow the white color shines through depending on the camera angle.. even if I remove the white material, the grey default color also shines through. If I separate the road to an own object, it works fine -but I don't think that this should be the solution :/
[image]
(Object Mode)

[image]
(Edit Mode)

[image]
(Face Orientation)

[image]
(Unity)

Comment: I know this page already & actual I did the same thing mentioned there. I successfully applied already 2 different materials to the object. But like you see.. it seems to be buggy because the color underneath shines somehow through. Even the default grey color shines through..

Comment: from the screenshots it looks like duplicated faces / vertices overlapping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *slightly* offset the road along the Z axis. This is what is called "Z-fighting" where the renderer does not know which material to render because the faces are overlapping, so they are randomly rendered on top of another.

Comment: But for this I have to split the road from the rest, right? So I have in the end 2 objects.  I mean, right now the object is hollow, so on the top there are "just" the road faces. Underneath there is no other face.

Comment: Well, I don't really understand how your model works. From what you are saying you might have double vertices. Select all your vertices in edit mode and choose right click > Merge > By distance. If that doesn't solve it would you mind sharing your blend file ? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: awesome thanks!!! The merging of vertices helped! So it seems, I had multiple faces overlapping each other... Also I checked, my starting part of the track had already doubled vertices.. I can't explain exactly how this happened, but nonetheless thanks a lot, problem is solved :)